# service worker app-shell PHP implementation

Tags: javascript, service-worker, postmessage, progressive-web-apps

I'm introducing service worker on my site.And i'm using app-shell approach for responding to requests.Below is my code structure.

serviceWorker.js

```
self.addEventListener("fetch", function(event) {
  if (requestUri.indexOf('-spid-') !== -1) {
    reponsePdPage(event,requestUri);
  }else{
    event.respondWith(fetch(requestUri,{mode: 'no-cors'}).catch(function (error){
        console.log("error in fetching => "+error);
        return new Response("not found");
        }) 
    );
  }
});


function reponsePdPage(event,requestUri){
   var appShellResponse=appShellPro();
   event.respondWith(appShellResponse);  //responds with app-shell
   event.waitUntil(
      apiResponse(requestUri)       //responds with dynamic content
   );
}

function appShellPro(){
   return fetch(app-shell.html);
}
function apiResponse(requestUri){
   var message=['price':'12.45cr'];
   self.clients.matchAll().then(function(clients){
    clients.forEach(function (client) {
        if(client.url == requestUri)
            client.postMessage(JSON.stringify(message));
    });
   });
}
```

App-shell.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
            if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
              navigator.serviceWorker.onmessage = function (evt) {
                var message = JSON.parse(evt.data);
                document.getElementById('price').innerHTML=message['price'];
              }
            }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="price"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**serviceWorker.js** is my only service worker file. whenever i'm getting request of -spid- in url i calls **reponsePdPage** function.In reponsePdPage function i'm first responding with **app-shell.html**. after that i'm calling **apiResponse** function which calls postmessage and send the dynamic data.The **listener** of **post message** is written in **app-shell.html**.

The issue i'm facing is, sometimes post message gets called before the listener registration.It means the **apiResponse** calls post message but their is not register listener to that event. So i cant capture the data.?Is their something wrong in my implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I'm going to focus on just the last bit, about the communication between the service worker and the controlled page. That question is separate from many of the other details you provide, such as using PHP and adopting the App Shell model.*

As you've observed, there's a race condition there, due to the fact that the code in the service worker and the parsing and execution of the HTML are performed in separate processes. I'm not surprised that the `onmessage` handler isn't established in the page yet at the time the service worker calls `client.postMessage()`.

You've got a few options if you want to pass information from the service worker to controlled pages, while avoiding race conditions.

The first, and probably simplest, option is to change the direction of communication, and have the controlled page use `postMessage()` to send a request to the service worker, which then responds with the same information. If you take that approach, you'll be sure that the controlled page is ready for the service worker's response. There's a full example [here](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/service-worker/post-message/index.html), but here's a simplified version of the relevant bit, which uses a Promise-based wrapper to handle the asynchronous response received from the service worker:

**Inside the controlled page:**

```
function sendMessage(message) {
  // Return a promise that will eventually resolve with the response.
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    var messageChannel = new MessageChannel();
    messageChannel.port1.onmessage = function(event) {
      resolve(event.data);
    };

    navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage(message,
      [messageChannel.port2]);
  });
}
```

**Inside the service worker:**

```
self.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
  // Check event.data to see what the message was.
  // Put your response in responseMessage, then send it back:
  event.ports[0].postMessage(responseMessage);
});
```

Other approaches include setting a value in IndexedDB inside the service worker, which is then read from the controlled page once it loads.

And finally, you could actually take the HTML you retrieve from the Cache Storage API, convert it into a string, modify that string to include the relevant information inline, and then respond with a new `Response` that includes the modified HTML. That's probably the most heavyweight and fragile approach, though.

Comment: If i use first approach i.e calling postMessage from controlled page , it means the service worker thread will sit idle untill i called the postMessage from the client. And in the second approach what if the service is not completed and i check for the value in IndexedDB.

Comment: I don't understand the concern about the service worker "sitting idle". It's not up to you to manage the execution of the service worker thread. The browser will decide to either kill the SW or keep it alive based on heuristics outside of your control. The important thing is that you can just call `postMessage()` and you'll (eventually) get back a response.

Comment: I mean to say that, as all the backend calculation is done in the second call(means **apiResponse** method) and the service worker will start this method only when i call the post message on client side. Isn't it be a good idea to start the api call after returning the app-shell and then put the results into cache.

Comment: If you have an remote API call that might take some time to finish, then you could start it from the controlled page via a `fetch('/path/to/api/endpoint')` and then use an appropriate caching strategy inside the SW's `fetch` handler, depending on how fresh the response needs to be. Something like https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/offline-cookbook/#cache-and-network-race